# FillRectangle is blurry

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

I've tried to draw pixelated tiled background by creating a brush from bitmap then drawing a rectangle with that brush:

```
e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(4, 4);

Bitmap tilemap = new Bitmap("tileset.png");
TextureBrush grassBrush = new TextureBrush(tilemap, WrapMode.Tile, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));

e.Graphics.FillRectangle(grassBrush, e.ClipRectangle);
```

But I'am getting this. The texture is blurry:

[image]

How would I make the `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(grassBrush, e.ClipRectangle);` draw pixelated nearest neighbor tiled texture?

Comment: BTW, are you disposing of your GDI objects correctly? (And you shouldn't load `new Bitmap` 
on every invocation of your `OnPaint` method: cache it in a field).

Comment: What DPI is Windows configured to run at? (judging from the screenshot I'm guessing 125% / 120dpi? - If so, then that will be the culprit: GDI didn't stretch/blur your `TextureBrush`, it's looking like WinForms historically terrible high-DPI support and/or the DWM scaling your window). Also, **exactly** what version of .NET and WinForms are you using?

Comment: Don't use `ScaleTransform()` for this. Draw the source image to a new Bitmap of size `64x64`, then set this new image to your `tilemap` object (as mentioned, created once, maybe in the Constructor of your Form, not in the Paint handler) -- When you create the copy, use both `[Graphics].InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor` and `[Graphics].PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Half`, not needed anymore in the Paint handler

Comment: @Dai the dpi is default 100%. The gdi canvas is scaled because of `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(4, 4);` call, but it is intended as I need to scale my TextureBrush, but I need the scaling in a nearest neighboor straight pixels, without any blurred interpolation. The `InterpolationMode` won't help :( It helps only when I draw a *single* image with `Graphics.DrawImage` yes it draws it pixelated, but here I need to draw a whole tiled(repeated) atlas I found I can draw it with TextureBrush and FillRectangle, and it blurs.

Comment: @Jimi thanks! But, is it only possible way and can't I tell GDI+ somehow not to use interpolation when filling rectangle with a textured brush? I am trying to write a simple 2D game, and I planned to alter the scale transformation dynamically. I see if I'll implement an animated camera zoom it will be a problem with creating a new scaled bitmap for every scale change.

Comment: @Dai I see :( Well then, it seems the only possible way to achieve what I wanted is to take a mipmap-like approach with creating 32x32, 24x24, 64x64 etc. nearest neighbor interpolated image copies and switching between them.

Comment: Do you mean that *simpler* to scale the Bitmap inside a scaled device context each time the Paint event is raised than it is to scale a Bitmap once when something in your app is scaled? -- When you change this *scale*, simply generate a new Bitmap from the original, setting its dimensions to a multiple of the original image, then draw the original into it using the aforementioned settings and assign it to `tilemap`. In this case, the Interpolation and PixelOffset are considered

Comment: Note that you can also use a nested loop and fill the client area with your bitmap, you don't necessarily need a TextureBrush. Or draw your bitmap inside a larger, scaled Bitmap, then draw this one (or assign it to the BackgroundImage property; you can do that even beforehand, then just invalidate the canvas. Many options)